# Meaning of Q H U

Tags: abbreviations

I've been reading a poem "[Song to Joannes](http://oncomouse.github.io/loy/songs.html)" by a futurist poet Mina Loy. Her poems are hard to interpret but there is one line that really confuses me.

> ...
>
> Nothing so conserving
>
> As cool cleaving
>
> **Note of the Q  H  U**
>
> Clear carving
>
> Breath-giving
>
> Pollen smelling
>
> Space
>
> ...

Apart from other seeming nonsense, there's this Q H U.

I'm asking here because this poem is supposedly dedicated to her Italian lover with whom she lived in Florence in 1915-16. So I thought that by "Note of the Q H U" she meant a note to/by her lover and "Q H U" can be some acronym in Italian. For example, "It was fantastic" or "See you tomorrow" or whatever.

My other guess it might be a note of some perfume because there's a line about smelling further on.

Any thoughts about what it can mean? Or if this Italian at all?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Nothing obvious springs to mind (it's certainly not a common Italian acronym), but maybe some other user will have ideas

Comment: @DenisNardin thanks. My other guess it might be a note of some perfume because there's a line about smelling further on.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the whole poem?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni added http://oncomouse.github.io/loy/songs.html

Comment: @OleksandrFediienko: Here there are possible meanings about QHU acronym: https://www.abbreviations.com/QHU

Comment: Could it be "quantum" something? I believe this poem has a smell of physics and these were the years of first developments on quantum physics.